# How to set max and min value for Y axis

Tags: chart.js

I am using line chart from http://www.chartjs.org/
[image]

As you can see max value (130) and min value (60) for Y axis are chosen automatically , I want max value = 500 and min value=0. Is this possible?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You have to overrride the scale, try this:  `(applies to ChartJS v1.x)`

```
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        scaleOverride : true,
        scaleSteps : 10,
        scaleStepWidth : 50,
        scaleStartValue : 0 
    });
}
```

Comment: Note this answer is relevant to the 1.x versions of chart.js The `scales` object in the 2.x versions is quite different. See @OferSegev answer below and the [2.x documentation here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/).

Comment: Is there documentation for v1.x as well @Boaz

Comment: @IshanMahajan There used to be :) I can't seem to find it anymore. I think this is a good mirror: https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20150816192112/http://www.chartjs.org:80/docs/

Answer (score 351):

For chart.js V2 (beta), use:

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 0,    // minimum will be 0, unless there is a lower value.
                // OR //
                beginAtZero: true   // minimum value will be 0.
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

See [chart.js documentation on linear axes configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html) for more details.

Comment: see also the `min`, `max`, and `stepsize` attributes of the `ticks` namespace

Comment: `suggestedMax` for the minimum top value

Answer (score 88):

```js
var config = {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
                datasets: [{
                        label: "My First dataset",
                        data: [10, 80, 56, 60, 6, 45, 15],
                        fill: false,
                        backgroundColor: "#eebcde ",
                        borderColor: "#eebcde",
                        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                        borderDash: [5, 5],
                    }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom',
                },
                hover: {
                    mode: 'label'
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: 'Month'
                            }
                        }],
                    yAxes: [{
                            display: true,
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                steps: 10,
                                stepValue: 5,
                                max: 100
                            }
                        }]
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Legend'
                }
            }
        };

        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
       new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Worked Just fine in 2.4.0

Comment: every version of ng2-charts is so annoyingly different that every SO answer on it is useless

Answer (score 82):

**Edit:**

They have made some changes. Currently, this is what will work

```
       scales: {
            x: {
                ...,
                max: value,
                min: value
            },
            y: {
                ...same as x
            }
        }
```

Here is the link to the latest changes
[min max chart js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.0/samples/scales/linear-min-max.html)

---

**Old answer:**

As of **Feb 2022**, this works. Here is how one can change it

```js
var options = {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
                min: 0, // minimum value
                max: 10 // maximum value
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: I would modify the answer to specify the versions instead of the date, since the answer to the question depends on the version. Chart.js 3.0 introduces a number of breaking changes including removing the xAxes and yAxes options, see https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.0/getting-started/v3-migration.html

Comment: no longer works with latest build

Answer (score 47):

ChartJS v2.4.0

As shown in the examples at https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js on the 7th of febuary 2017 (since this seems to be subject to frequent change):

```
var options = {
    yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            stepSize: 20
        }
    }]
}
```

This will result in 5 y-axis values as such:

```
100
80
60
40
20
0
```

Comment: I'm surprised this works because I thought the `xAxes` and `yAxes` were supposed to be nested under `scales` in the options.  That plus this is newer than Ofer Sergev's answer which appears to be correct is also surprising.

Answer (score 26):

For `"chart.js": "^3.6.1",`

```
options: {          
    scales: {
        y: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: April 2022 Chart.js v3.6.0: It's a pity this answer is not closer to the top of the page. I went through all previous answers unsuccessfully before trying this one which does exactly what I expected it to do.

Comment: Same as @Rodent. Many mention the min/max inside `ticks`, but that doesn't work! The above answer is correct and it took me many tries as well. It "forces" the Y scale to fixed min/max regardless of what the data values are.

Comment: Same as @Fid, other answers are **not forcing** the chart to max value. This works like charm!

Answer (score 22):

For Chart.js v3.2.0, do this:

```
let options = {
    scales: {
        y: {
            suggestedMin: 0,
            suggestedMax: 69
        },
        x: {
            suggestedMin: 0,
            suggestedMax: 420
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/#axis-range-settings

Comment: Nice to see someone actually reference chartJS 3 rarther than old v1 or v2 versions.

Comment: this worked for me, Thank you.

My angular environment had configured like below,

......
"@angular/cdk": "^15.2.6",
"chart.js": "^4.3.0",
"ng2-charts": "^4.1.1",
......

Answer (score 18):

I wrote a js to display values from 0 to 100 in y-axis with a gap of 20.

This is my script.js

```js
//x-axis
var vehicles = ["Trucks", "Cars", "Bikes", "Jeeps"];

//The percentage of vehicles of each type
var percentage = [41, 76, 29, 50];

var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart");
var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: vehicles,
    datasets: [{
      data: percentage,
      label: "Percentage of vehicles",
      backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          stepSize: 20,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

This is the graph displayed on the web.

[image: Percentage of vehicles in the town]

Answer (score 17):

```
window.onload = function(){
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx ,{
          type: 'line',
          data: yourData,
          options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 500    
                    }
                  }]
               }
            }
});
```

I configure with 'options' in v2.

You should read documentation:
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-linear-scale

Comment: Thanks. This one worked for me on v2.5 of chart.js. Simple and effective.

Comment: The docs are so frustrating... I have to search people examples to guess the options available.

Comment: If someone is using pure javascript, this answer is the correct one. I wrote a small example using this and I posted my complete js code below.

Answer (score 14):

The above answers didn't work for me. Possibly the option names were changed since '11, but the following did the trick for me:

```
ChartJsProvider.setOptions
  scaleBeginAtZero: true
```

Answer (score 9):

---

**> Best Solution**

---

```
  "options":{
                    scales: {
                                yAxes: [{
                                    display: true,
                                    ticks: {
                                        suggestedMin: 0, //min
                                        suggestedMax: 100 //max 
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                    }
```

Comment: Please provide a better description of your solution than "Best Solution". Also I would specify the versions since the answer to the question depends on the version. Chart.js 3.0 introduces a number of breaking changes including removing the xAxes and yAxes options, see chartjs.org/docs/3.7.0/getting-started/v3-migration.html

Answer (score 8):

Just set the value for **scaleStartValue** in your options.

```
var options = {
   // ....
   scaleStartValue: 0,
}
```

See the documentation for this [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration).

Comment: This answer is better for me as it explicits how to choose the scale start value, if not 0

Answer (score 8):

```
yAxes: [{
    display: true,
    ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        steps:10,
        stepValue:5,
        max:100
    }
}]
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 6):

This is for Charts.js 2.0:

The reason some of these are not working is because you should declare your options when you create your chart like so:

```
$(function () {
    var ctxLine = document.getElementById("myLineChart");
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctxLine, {
        type: 'line',
        data: dataLine,
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        min: 0,
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }

    });
})
```

Documentation for this is here: 
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales

Comment: Is this adapting for changes in ChartJS that came with version 2.0 (I think the question and accepted answer one year ago dealt with ChartJS 1.x). Maybe this answer would even be more helpful if this is shortly explained. Maybe just comment on this comment if time allows. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't need to use `beginAtZero`.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I used a callback in yaxis ticks,
my values are in percent and when it reaches 100% it doesn't show the dot, I used this :

```
      yAxes: [{
                   ticks: {
                       beginAtZero: true,
                       steps: 10,
                       stepValue: 5,
                       min: 0,
                       max: 100.1,
                       callback: function(value, index, values) {
                           if (value !== 100.1) {
                               return values[index]
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }],
```

And it worked well.

Comment: irrelevant to this question?

Comment: Partly, I also added a solution to a problem that he is likely to encounter.

Answer (score 4):

There's so many conflicting answers to this, most of which had no effect for me.

I was finally able to set (or retrieve current) X-axis minimum & maximum displayed values with `chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.min` (even if min & max are only a subset of the data assigned to the chart.)

Using a time scale in my case, I used:

```
chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.min = 1590969600000;  //Jun 1, 2020
chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].ticks.max = 1593561600000;  //Jul 1, 2020
chart.update();
```

(I found no need to set the step values or `beginAtZero`, etc.)

Comment: his is the only working answer for me.

Answer (score 3):

### v3.X (v3.5.0)

#### Linear Cartesian Axis

```json
let options = {
  scales: {
    y: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      suggestedMax: 69
    },
    x: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      suggestedMax: 420
    },
    ticks: {
      stepSize: 1
    }
  }
}
```

Ref. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.0/axes/cartesian/linear.html

#### Linear Radial Axes

```json
let options = {
  scales: {
    r: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      suggestedMax: 5,
      ticks: {
        stepSize: 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ref. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.0/axes/radial/linear.html

### v2.X (v2.9.4)

#### Linear Cartesian Axis

```json
let options = {
    scale: {
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        stepSize: 1,
        suggestedMax: 5,
      }
    }
}
```

Ref. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/cartesian/linear.html

#### Linear Radial Axes

```json
let options = {
  scale: {
    ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      stepSize: 1,
      suggestedMax: 5,
    }
  }
}
```

Ref. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/axes/radial/linear.html

Note: scale in singular in v2 and plural in v3

Answer (score 2):

With 1.1.1, I used the following to fix the scale between 0.0 and 1.0:

```
var options = {
    scaleOverride: true,
    scaleStartValue: 0,
    scaleSteps: 10,
    scaleStepWidth: 0.1
}
```

Comment: answer outdated

Answer (score 2):

As of the latest version v3.9.1, you can set your scale like this :

```
options:{
    scales:{
        y:{
            beginAtZero: true,
            max: 500 // values over 500 will be hidden, OR
            suggestedMax: 500, // maximum will be 500, unless there is a higher value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the suggestions above helped me with charts.js 2.1.4, I solved it by adding the value 0 to my data set array (but no extra label):

```
statsData.push(0);

[...]

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            data: statsData,
[...]
```

Comment: its shocking how none of the answers worked for me except for this one! beginAtZero and suggestedMin are broken for small values