# react I want to adjust the display area of the y-axis in react-chart-2

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I am using react-chart-2.
I would like to set the minimum value of the y-axis to 0 and the maximum value to 100.
Now, the y-axis is determined according to the data value.
How can I customize the value of the y-axis?

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-hill-qqh83?file=/src/App.tsx:0-644)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";

const App = () => {
  const data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "a",
        data: [30, 10, 10, 40, 20, 10, 30],
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  };

  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            max: 1000,
            min: 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Line data={data} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45793890/set-max-value-for-y-axis-in-react-chart?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I went to the above site and implemented the same way, but the minimum and maximum values did not change.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-hill-qqh83?file=/src/App.tsx