# How to offset axes in a scatter plot?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want a little extra space around my data points in a scatter plot, between the extremum points and the axis.

[Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/) lists the supposedly common `offset` property which sounds exactly like what I want, but it seems to only work for the horizontal labeled axis (first half of the snippet). It does nothing whatsoever for a scatter plot (second half).

Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply unsupported? What can I do as a workaround?

```js
var options, ctx;

options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [0, 1, 2],
    datasets: [{
      data: [0, 1, 0]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        offset: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        offset: true
      }]
    }
  }
}

ctx = document.getElementById('chart1').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);

options = {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }, {
        x: 1,
        y: 1
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 0
      }]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        offset: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        offset: true
      }]
    }
  }
}

ctx = document.getElementById('chart2').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chart1" height="100"></canvas>
</body>

<body>
  <canvas id="chart2" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the `offset` working as you expect. Note that even on the first graph, the yaxis is not doing that padding.

I'd [look](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html) [into](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553748) `suggestedMin` and `suggestedMax` as shown below:

```js
var options, ctx;

options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [0, 1, 2],
    datasets: [{
      data: [0, 1, 0]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        offset: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        offset: true
      }]
    }
  }
}

ctx = document.getElementById('chart1').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);

options = {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }, {
        x: 1,
        y: 1
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 0
      }]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        ticks: {
            suggestedMin: -1,    // minimum will be -1, unless there is a lower value.
            suggestedMax: 3
        }
    }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        ticks: {
            suggestedMin: -1,    // minimum will be -1, unless there is a lower value.
            suggestedMax: 2
        }
    }]
    }
  }
}

ctx = document.getElementById('chart2').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chart1" height="100"></canvas>
</body>

<body>
  <canvas id="chart2" height="100"></canvas>
</body>
```