# Show small chart using Chartjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I want to achieve the following chart (a small 7 day chart):

[image]

For that, I started using [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/) with React. My knowledge is limited with ChartJS.

My Line chart options are:

```
const options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        title: {
            display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
            enabled: false
        },
    },
    elements: {
        point:{
            radius: 0
        }
    },
    tooltips:{
        enabled: false
    },
    hover: {mode: null},
    scales: {
        x: {
            display: false,
        },
        y: {
            display: false,
        }
    },
    animation: {
        duration: 0
    },
    parsing: {
        xAxisKey: 'time',
        yAxisKey: 'value'
    }
}

const dataOptions = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [] // i fill this when the component is mounted,
}
```

And then I add a chart:

```
<Line
    data={dataOptions}
    options={options}>
</Line>
```

I get:

[image]

I need the max and min to be adjust so it looks rather a smoother chart.

How can I achieve the first image - as mine looks very basic, and what is usual for small 7 day charts?

Answer (score 1):

Your questions is not clear to me.
The differences I can see between what you said you want and what you said you get is (for me):

- yours has a purple line instead of green line
- yours has a less chart height
- yours has much less data

What you say as smooth seems to be that you just has much less data (the above has hundreds of datapoints, yours only ~20.
Increase your data and it will look smoother.

To get a higher chart height, I referr to this other thread:
[How to set max and min value for Y axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990708/how-to-set-max-and-min-value-for-y-axis)
you can use suggestedMin/Max in the scales-ticks-option.

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        y: {
            suggestedMax: 1000, // maximum value will be 1000.
            suggestedMin: 100, // minimum value will be 100.
            // OR //
            beginAtZero: true   // minimum value will be 0.
        }
    }
};
```

chart Size in chartJs is a big thing.
You already are using

```
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false,
```

Which leads to chartJs try to use the space it needs and gets from outer element (e.g. a div).
But for me it is still difficult to get it working 100%. Sometimes some css may crush that behavior.

If you are new to chart JS I really recommend their own website having many samples and a online-engine where you can try out any option.
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/linear-min-max-suggested.html

Test your stuff there first before coding on your site.
You can edit the option in their live samples and directly see the effects.

Comment: You are using an old and unsupported way of defining scales in the last 2 versions. You might want to update that and use the new format in next answers https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.1/getting-started/v3-migration.html#specific-changes

Comment: yes, your are right, i just copied the code from the related thread, did not note that its outdated, i updated it